# ASP: passing values between web forms

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Im trying to pass a value of a date control from form1 to form2.

on form 1.aspx.vb:

```
   Public ReadOnly Property Property1() As Date
        Get
            Return StartDate.SelectedDate
        End Get
    End Property
```

On Form2.aspx:

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/form1.aspx" %>
```

On form2.aspx.vb:

```
 Label14.Text = PreviousPage.Property1
```

when I run it, the compiler gives me an error:

`"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

with marking in red:

```
Label14.Text = PreviousPage.Property1
```

Tried to assign the property to a string, it did not work either.

Any suggestions ???

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the Form2.aspx page is accessed directly without cross-page posting, then PreviousPage property is null. You should add this check before retrieving value of Property1:

```
if (PreviousPage != null && PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack) {
    Label14.Text = PreviousPage.Property1
}
```

Using PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/form1.aspx" directive is a little bit dangerous when other page than Form1.aspx do cross-page post to Form2. PreviousPage property throws InvalidCastException (it expects Form1 page but it gets something else).

For more information see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I think Startdate isn't declared / initialized, how do you set the data for this readonly property?